# How do you feel about including ie7.js or ie8.js in your page?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, cross-browser

See here: http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/

Does anyone have any experience or remarks about this javascript?  Is it worth including?  Do you recommend it?

Comment: I've never used it, but it looks pretty sweet.. thanks for the link. :)

Comment: I am looking to just fix the <button type=submit> problem using the ie8.js, so I don't want the other stuff.  Anyone have any experience in removing unused functionality?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I know many people, myself included that are using various IE hacks to get transparent PNG support.  THis looks like a little bit more help, and as long as it works, and the size is fairly small, I wouldn't see much against using it.

Comment: Agreed.  If it contains a significant amount of workaround code that you would otherwise have to write yourself, use the library.

Answer (score 10):

I've used it before, and my results are mixed. Those scripts cause IE to churn for a bit on page load. Basically, you have to think of it as iterating through Elements and stylesheet rules to apply "fixes" for areas that are deficient in that particular rendering engine. In some cases, depending on how complicated your markup or stylesheets are, that can take a bit of time and you will see the browser hang.

That said, if you can trade off that performance cost, you will save development time as you'll spend less time hacking around IE6 quirks; IE7/IE8 will provide enough missing functionality that you can avoid certain edge cases, can develop using standards better (min-width/min-height, multiple className selectors, etc.), and certain rendering issues will disappear.

However, if you just need 24-bit transparent PNG support, use a tool built for that. Including IE7/IE8.js for PNG support alone is like pounding in a nail with a tank. Use DD_belatedPNG for that.

Answer (score 5):

It works, but its worth keeping in mind that ie7.js and ie8.js do much more than provide transparent PNG support. Even with the transparent PNG support, its worth keeping in mind that transparent background images cannot be tiled (repeated) using background-repeat or positioned using background-position. This hinders any ability to use CSS rollovers using background-position. I've only used it on one site I've done, and now that I'm updating the site I can't remove the ie8.js because if I do the entire website breaks layout in IE. I don't believe I'll be using it in the future, and instead rely on simple CSS hacks or simply allow my sites to "degrade gracefully" in IE6.

Answer (score 4):

I know that there are some tools for fixing the transparent PNG problem which are more flexible than this. For instance, the jQuery plugin [ifixpng2](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/iFixPng2) will support background position, which ie7-js doesn't do.

Answer (score 3):

As long as you are aware of exactly what it fixes, I would say go for it.  I'm not sure about this lib exactly, but some libs get very expensive if you have a large DOM, as they tend to hook in HTC file base behaviors on EVERY DOM Element.  This causes the dreaded "Loading x of y" status bar message to flash constantly on the initial load, and any newly generated DOM content.

Answer (score 1):

well its beautiful and works grate way u can use cs3 features like li:hover. we did lost of project last time using ie8.js and it works great way.